# How to select single ID from each day with last values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple ID's with multiple status change over multiple days.
There are some Id's with 2-3 status recorded in one day, I want all the ID's and their status at EOD

Eg: I want ID A and its EOD value on 09/09/20 (status Y in this case) plus I want ID A on 09/15/20 and its status

ID | date_Time      | Status|
A    09/09/20 9 am      X
A    09/09/20 5 pm      Y
A    09/15/20 3 pm      X
B    09/09/20 9 am      X
B    09/09/20 5 pm      Y

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow: Please share a Minimal Reproducible Example of your Code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Otherwise, looking at your question, it is very difficult to help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)